# Highcharts 3D Pie Chart - angles live update

Tags: highcharts

Is there a reason why pie chart angles cannot be updated live (as is the case for other charts).

I'm trying to achieve the same effect as for the column chart (to update the angels when the slider is changed), but the only thing that changes for a pie chart are the labels (they move in the right direction, but the chart does not).

The HighCharts demo for 3D Column Chart: https://www.highcharts.com/demo/3d-column-interactive

My Pie Chart live demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/highcharts-angular-3d-pie-chart?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

Indeed the value cannot be changed. This is because the pie chart is structured differently from the rest of the charts, you can see the details in core.

> For a pie chart the depth of the total chart is not important and setting the frame does not do anything (the frame is linked to the axis line and pies do not have these in the same way the other charts have). For pie charts it is important to set the depth property in plotOptions.

https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/3d-charts

```
        Pie3DSeries.prototype.translate = function () {
            _super.prototype.translate.apply(this, arguments);
            // Do not do this if the chart is not 3D
            if (!this.chart.is3d()) {
                return;
            }
            var series = this,
                seriesOptions = series.options,
                depth = seriesOptions.depth || 0,
                options3d = series.chart.options.chart.options3d,
                alpha = options3d.alpha,
                beta = options3d.beta,
                z = seriesOptions.stacking ?
                    (seriesOptions.stack || 0) * depth :
                    series._i * depth;
            z += depth / 2;
            if (seriesOptions.grouping !== false) {
                z = 0;
            }
            series.data.forEach(function (point) {
                var shapeArgs = point.shapeArgs,
                    angle;
                point.shapeType = 'arc3d';
                shapeArgs.z = z;
                shapeArgs.depth = depth * 0.75;
                shapeArgs.alpha = alpha;
                shapeArgs.beta = beta;
                shapeArgs.center = series.center;
                angle = (shapeArgs.end + shapeArgs.start) / 2;
                point.slicedTranslation = {
                    translateX: Math.round(Math.cos(angle) *
                        seriesOptions.slicedOffset *
                        Math.cos(alpha * deg2rad)),
                    translateY: Math.round(Math.sin(angle) *
                        seriesOptions.slicedOffset *
                        Math.cos(alpha * deg2rad))
                };
            });
        };
        return Pie3DSeries;
    }(PieSeries));
    extend(Pie3DSeries.prototype, {
        pointClass: Pie3DPoint
    });
```

Source:
https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-3d.src.js

Demo:
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/7s4vL5p2/